# How can I pass instance variables to a HAML template on the command line?

Tags: ruby, haml, command-line-interface, interpolation, instance-variables

### Background

I'm trying to test the formatting of some HAML templates *outside* of Rails. The idea is to pass in some instance variables on the command line or via an included Ruby file, rendering the template to standard output. I tried this several different ways without success, as outlined below.

### Requiring a Ruby File

For example, given the following two files:

- HAML template: "test.haml"

  ```
  !!!
  %h1 Testing HAML CLI
  %p= @bar
  %p= @baz
  ```
- Ruby file: "test.rb"

  ```
  @foo = 'abc'
  @bar = '123'
  ```

I would expect an invocation like `haml -r ./test test.haml` to return an interpolated HTML file on standard output, but it doesn't. Instead, I get just the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Testing HAML CLI</h1>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

### Programmatic Attempt

Since this didn't work, I also tried to do this programmatically. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'haml'

@foo = 'abc'
@bar = '123'

engine = Haml::Engine.new(File.read 'test.haml')
puts engine.render
```

with exactly the same results, e.g. just the HTML with no variable interpolation.

### Restating the Question

Clearly, something else is needed to get HAML to render the template with its associated variables. I would prefer to do this from the command line, either by passing arguments or including a file. How should I be invoking HAML from the command line to make it happen?

If that's not possible for whatever reason, how should I invoke HAML programmatically to perform the interpolation without depending on Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that both of these examples are not working is that you are attempting to access instance variables from a different class. The simplest solution is to define and use methods instead of attempting to access another classes instance variables as if they were your own.

I.E. in test.rb

```
def foo
  'abc'
end
```

test.haml

```
!!!
%h1 Testing HAML CLI
%p= foo
```

Answer (score 13):

You can supply a scope object and a local variables hash to the `render` method. In your example case, you would call:

```
engine = Haml::Engine.new(File.read 'test.haml')
engine.render(Object.new, { :@foo => 'abc', :@bar => '123' })
```

Comment: How would this work if my template uses a hash like `= @params['description']`? I tried doing `haml_engine.render(Object.new, @params)` but I get `NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: For me, your syntax is wrong in { :@foo => 'abc' } I have to remove the @.
Any reason it's there in your example?

Comment: @PandaWood The original question contained a template using instance variables. Perhaps yours is different?

Comment: @ZachKemp Silly me, of course, I wasn't using instance variables